# matlab hotkey for figure copy

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, hotkeys

How to define matlab hotkeys for specific task. Specifically, I usually need to use the "copy figure" with high frequency when using figures. How can I assign a shortcut (hotkey) for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a hotkey to a menu item can be done by finding the handle to the uimenu object and adding an accelerator.

E.g. in order to set the hotkey to `Ctrl+ H` simply run:

```
set(findall(gcf,'type','uimenu','tag','figMenuEditCopyFigure'),'Accelerator','H')
```

to change the current figure, or

```
set(findall(0,'type','uimenu','tag','figMenuEditCopyFigure'),'Accelerator','H')
```

to change all figures.

Alternatively, if you wish to copy the figure to clipboard automatically from code you can use `print`.

```
print('-clipboard','-dmeta') (Vector graphic, WINDOWS ONLY)
% or
print('-clipboard','-dbitmap') (bitmap graphic)
```

#### Update

In reply to your comment a way to alter all future figures is (not recommended) to create your own `plot` (or whatever function) function earlier in your path that looks something like this:

```
function varargout=plot(varargin)
    varargout=cell(1,nargout);
    [varargout{:}]=builtin('plot',varargin{:});

    set(findall(gcf,'type','uimenu','tag','figMenuEditCopyFigure'),'Accelerator','H');
end
```

Which essentially firstly calls the built-in function `plot` and forwards its output and then runs the above oneliner to update the current figure.

Comment: Thank you it worked, but do you know a way to alter "acceleration" property in "groot". Actually the way you have presented does the job for opened figures. but I want it to be done for figures to be created (future figures). That way if I add the command to startup, I will have the answer altogether.

Comment: My oneliner only changes existing `uimenu` objects. In order to change how these standard `uimenu` objects are created you'd probably somehow have to alter the standard figure creation process. 

By changing `gcf` for `0` you can alter all existing figures instead of only the current figure. 

Another option is to create your own `plot` (or whatever) function earlier in your path that calls the built in function and then runs the aforementioned oneliner.

Comment: Added a suggested function outline that should do the trick assuming you are using a built-in function to plot.

Answer (score 0):

The keymap of Matlab can be altered in the preferences menu. A more detailed information about all the options is given on the [specific help page of Mathworks](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/keyboard-shortcuts.html).

```
Home -> Environment -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that in that page the Copy Figure is not reachable. but I guess there is a file (may be xml) whose alteration should give the result I want.

Comment: I will check it when I get home.

Comment: Can you be maybe a bit more clear about what you mean with copy figure? Because when I make a plot, in a figure, I don't see any option to copy the figure. And if there is no option, then making a shortcut would be very hard, maybe impossible.

Comment: in a figure, go to "Edit" then choose "Copy Figure", this is what I use very much. Also I want to know how to create shortcuts for other options in these menus which should be similar (supposedly).